# ASP.Net Scheduled Task Executing Method by Multiples

Tags: asp.net, task

Credit to the author from this site:

https://codinginfinite.com/creating-scheduler-task-seconds-minutes-hours-days/

I can define the task execution parameter in 24hr time to run my method, but I see no logic in the code that is clear to me as to why it fires my method by a large multiplicity of times.  The issue is that where my method should be executed only but once per minute starting at the specified time, it is actually executed 20+ times in less than one minute.  I've tried altering parameters and repeat intervals, but nothing seems to resolve the issue and different execution intervals always fire the method many times over than what is specified - i.e. similarly, 5min interval, but I get 30+ order placements within one minute whereas I would expect not more than one order execution every 5 minutes..

Any ideas on why this could be happening with this code?

Here is the service class:

```
public class SchedulerService
    {                
        private static SchedulerService _instance;
        private List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();
        private SchedulerService() { }
        public static SchedulerService Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new SchedulerService());
        public void ScheduleTask(int hour, int min, double intervalInHour, Action task)
        {            
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime firstRun = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, min, 0, 0);

            if (now > firstRun)
            {
                firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
            }
            
            TimeSpan timeToGo = firstRun - now;
            if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }   
            
            var timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                task.Invoke();
            }, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.FromHours(intervalInHour));
            timers.Add(timer);            
        }
    }
```

Here is the scheduler class:

```
public class Scheduler
    {
        public static void IntervalInSeconds(int hour, int sec, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval / 3600;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, sec, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInMinutes(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval / 60;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInHours(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInDays(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval * 24;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
    }
```

Instantiated on page load with defined start time parameters and repeat interval:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scheduler.IntervalInMinutes(20, 15, 1,
        () => {
            buyOrder();
        });
    }
```

At 20:15, call this method and repeat every minute:

```
    private static void buyOrder()
    {
        //This is only a basic POST method
    }
```

Result:

I get the multiplicity of orders executed in <1min as mentioned.

Comment: The code seems sound. Executing this on `Page_Load` seems suspicious to me. Is it possible `Page_Load` is executing several times for some reason (thereby scheduling several jobs within milliseconds/seconds from each other)?

Comment: I have some JavaScripts running at load to establish a websocket connection with my broker's server to authenticate and stream data.  Could that potentially be why?

Comment: If they are causing a request to the page then sure. What I would recommend is that you insert a logging statement on the Page_Load method and record useful information about the call (e.g. postback state, referrer, etc). Another common issue to watch out for is inheritance in base classes. Sometimes an event handler is mistakenly added to one more steps in the inheritance chain which causes this behavior. The framework will wire that up for you so there is no need to bound the event manually.

Comment: It should be only performing authentication to establish the TCP link, but perhaps there is more going on under the hood I'm not aware of.  I'll implement the suggested logging and see if there's anything noticeable, as I'd rather prefer to have to condition trigger at loading the page, if possible.  Either way, thanks for the very helpful inputs, Juan - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears not to be in the code but rather the fact that you are running the scheduling instruction in the `Page_Load` event.

My educated guess is if you debug this, you will find that your `Page_Load` event is firing multiple times which causes multiple jobs to be scheduled.

There are a number of reasons why this could happen (like multiple event handlers, Ajax requests, or even the act of debugging through the code itself as some browsers will reissue requests if they don't receive a timely response) but the bottom line is you should rethink how/where you trigger the scheduling.

Comment: Thanks, Juan.  I did try testing with a button click event before to see if that would work, but it didn't at that time.  Perhaps it was something else.  I moved it to a click event again and it's firing off as expected.  I'll have to see where the best placement might be if not on Page_Load.

Comment: @sffc I am glad I was able to help. Good luck!